# How do I wait until all areas are registered with CustomizableUI in bootstrap.js::startup()?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I'm building a restartless add-on that is a `CustomizableUI` widget.

When I call `CustomizableUI.createWidget()` during `startup()`, I want the `defaultArea` property to be one of a selection of preferred areas. Currently I'm achieving this with something like this:

```
// ordered from most to least preferred
let preferredAreas = [
  'ctraddon_addon-bar',
  'ctraddon_extra-bar',
  CustomizableUI.AREA_BOOKMARKS,
  CustomizableUI.AREA_NAVBAR,
  // null basically translates to 'PanelUI-contents'
  // but this makes it easy to test later on
  null
];

let registeredAreas = CustomizableUI.areas;
let preferredArea;
for( let i = 0, l = preferredAreas.length; i < l; i++ ) {
  preferredArea = preferredAreas[ i ];
  if( registeredAreas.indexOf( preferredArea ) > -1 ) {
    break;
  }
}

if( !preferredArea ) { // i.e. null
  /* on first run: notify user that we were unable to find a preferred area */
}

CustomizableUI.createWidget( {
  id: 'myAddon',
  type: 'custom',
  defaultArea: preferredArea,
  /* etc */
} );
```

In other words: I'm checking if any preferred area is present. This works pretty much as expected, in `startup()`, immediately after install, because basically then all areas of interest (from other extensions, such as Classic Theme Restorer) have registered already. However, when my add-on is already installed and Firefox starts up, `CustomizableUI.areas` is not filled with all areas of interest yet (probably because my extension loads earlier than the extension that registers areas of interest).

I've tried utilizing `mostRecentWindow.addEventListener( 'load', /* etc */ )`, where `mostRecentWindow` is the return value of `nsIWindowMediator.getMostRecentWindow( 'navigator:browser' )`, but:

1. on app startup `mostRecentWindow` will be `null`
2. on add-on install `mostRecentWindow` won't fire the `load` event anymore

So, my question is: what is a simple and effective way to wait with calling `CustomizableUI.createWidget()` until all relevant code has loaded?

---

What I ended up doing is the following (which is what Noitidart suggested as well), which seems to work:

```
let createWidget = function() {
    /* all the preferredArea and CustomizableUI.createWidget() stuff from above */
}

let mostRecentBrowserWindow = windowMediator.getMostRecentWindow( 'navigator:browser' );
if( null == mostRecentBrowserWindow ) {
  let windowListenerWidget = {
    onOpenWindow: function( wrappedWindow ) {
      windowMediator.removeListener( windowListenerWidget );
      let domWindow = wrappedWindow.QueryInterface( Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor )
                                   .getInterface( Ci.nsIDOMWindow );
      domWindow.addEventListener( 'load', function onWindowLoad( event ) {
        this.removeEventListener( 'load', onWindowLoad );
        createWidget();
      } );
    }
  }
  windowMediator.addListener( windowListenerWidget );
}
else {
  createWidget();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is add a listener for `onAreaNodeRegistered`. In the callback then create your widget.

See [MDN :: CustomizableUI.jsm - addListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm#addListener%28%29)

the onAreaNodeRegistered and onAreaNodeUnregsitered aren't on mdn so here is the definitons: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/customizableui/src/CustomizableUI.jsm#2704

```
2704    *   - onAreaNodeRegistered(aArea, aContainer)
2705    *     Fired after an area node is first built when it is registered. This
2706    *     is often when the window has opened, but in the case of add-ons,
2707    *     could fire when the node has just been registered with CustomizableUI
2708    *     after an add-on update or disable/enable sequence.
2709    *   - onAreaNodeUnregistered(aArea, aContainer, aReason)
2710    *     Fired when an area node is explicitly unregistered by an API caller,
2711    *     or by a window closing. The aReason parameter indicates which of
2712    *     these is the case.
2713    */
```

So for implementaiton do this:

First check if the area you want exists. If it doesn't then add a listener. And in the listener do the create widget:

```
var targetAreaId = 'blah'; //the id of area you want test for, meaning the area you want to add your widget too, targetAreaId can be CustomizableUI.AREA_NAVBAR, basically its the id (first arg) argument of CustomizableUI.registerArea('blahIdHere'..

function createMyWidget() {
  CustomizableUI.addWidget({
     id: "edit-controls",
    type: "custom",
    defaultArea: targetAreaId,
    onBuild: function(aDocument) {}
    //........ blah blah balh
  })
}


if (CustomizableUI.areas.indexOf(targetAreaId) > -1) { // customizableUI.areas is an array for example for me it is:`Array [ "PanelUI-contents", "nav-bar", "toolbar-menubar", "TabsToolbar", "PersonalToolbar", "addon-bar", "thePuzzlePiece-addon-bar" ]`
  createMyWidget();
} else {    
    var myCustUiListener = {
      'onAreaNodeRegistered': function(aArea, aContainer) {
        //create your widget here
        if (aArea.id == targetAreaId) { //im not sure of the properties on aArea do a console.log('aArea properties:', aArea) to see what all properties are there
         createMyWidget();
        }
      }
    };
    CustomizableUI.addListener(myCustUiListener);
}
```

Comment: Hi Noitidart, thank you for your answer. I am going to look into this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I see what you are trying to do. Thing is: I don't want to wait indefinitely for a certain area. I just want to see whether certain area's are available at Firefox start-up (after Firefox has completely loaded), and if not, just have `defaultArea` be `null` (which basically means put it in the customization palette). Furthermore: it's probably just a formality anyway, since during install all areas were already present. I just want `CustomizableUI.createWidget()` to have consistent input on subsequent `startup()` calls. Perhaps I should save the initial area somewhere.

Comment: So, I guess my question basically boils down to: can I somehow observe that Firefox has completely finished loading, at startup? (If that actually makes any sense.)

Comment: Oh I see. So actually `CustomizableUI.areas.indexOf(aTargetAreaId)` should work right? But the issue is on startup you should probably wait for first window to finish loading right? So like on startup of your addon, iterate through all `nsIDOMWindow`s chcking if any of them have completely loaded, and if they hvae then its safe to use the `.areas.indexOf` I think. If no window is loaded yet, then use `windowListener` to listen to first load of `nsIDOMWindow` and on load of it then remove your window listener and run your customize code. What do you think?

Comment: Ha, that's funny. That is exactly what I just did, just now. I'll update my question with what I did. If you incorporate your last comment into your answer I'm marking it as the best answer! :)

Comment: Cool man thanks. Just clarification though: So the reason we want to wait for load of window is to allow any adons to do their `registerArea` not because we are waiting for `CustomizableUI.areas` to populate with the already registered areas. Because when CustomizableUI module loads it loads with all previously registered areas, so if CustomizableUI.areas is accessible then it means whatever is there is registered and the only way new ones can come in is if an addon or something else does new registration.

Comment: That is correct: [`CustomizableUI.areas`](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/customizableui/src/CustomizableUI.jsm#3113) is populated on each invocation. But if an add-on, that registers areas I'm interested in, loads later than my own add-on, it will not be available yet through `CustomizableUI.areas`. So that is, indeed, why I need to wait for a window to load.

Comment: You stated much more clearly than I did thanks man! Awesome discussion we had here! :)

Comment: Yeah! :) If you feel like it, be sure to incorporate your comment into your answer, so I can mark it as best. I want to award you the points (especially since you're often here to think along with me) but also want to make sure the proper information is in the answer before marking it as best.

Comment: Thanks man Ill post up another solution below with window listener example. Im a bit busy so cant do any coding right now :(